# svn diff summarize

Tags: svn

I want to get collated changed files across certain revision sets.
Something like this :
svn diff --summarize -r2949:3594,3925:4007,4015:4153 repo-url

Any hacks on this svn command to achieve this ?

regds,

Comment: because of the comma in between revision sets. probably this isn't a valid syntax

Answer (score 3):

I don't see a way to do what you are exactly requesting, however not know exactly what you are trying to accomplish, I am assuming that you only want to look at the diffs for certain files.  As Such you could use an external diff command to get the info you need.  for instance here's one that shows diff for everything but files with 'table' in them.

```
# svn diff --diff-cmd=/usr/bin/diff --extensions='-uw --exclude="*table*"'
```

If you want to exclude many files then you would need to use the --exclude-from directive.  Read the man page very carefully.  Here's an example exclude file that I have for this purpose

```
*cache*
file*
error_log
Images
dev.sett.php
server.sett.php.dev
manifest
manifest.uuid
migrate
school_deploy.sql
noimage_20_20_square.png
noimage_20_20square.png
noimage_50_20square.png
noimage_5020square.png
server.sett.php
*fsl
*FOSSIL*
```